# Grouped Products in Search

Tags: search, grouped-products

Does anyone have any insight on how Magento handles Grouped Products in search? For example, if a site has products 1, 2, 3 inside of grouped product 4, when searching for a search term that is contained it product 3's description, would product 4 be returned by the search? If not, is there a way to alter this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search indexers should concatenate all the searchable attributes for the grouped product and its associated/child products. You can verify this by looking at the `data_index` column in the `catalogsearch_fulltext` table. In your example for ID 4 you would see the descriptions and names of products 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Little hint is make keywords searchable and use search phrases or keywords to help build the search index. Works great for my site which has 50k items.